# How to consume Oracle API in android

Tags: android, oracle, oracle9i

I have following questions regarding Oracle API.

1. How to hit the oracle API from my android phone? Is it an plain http hit?
2. What will be the nature of response of oracle API? Is it Json or anything else?
3. If I am consuming Oracle API in my Application then what is the difference between consuming/hitting any normal API and Oracle API?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to a set of functions and stored procedures as **Oracle APIs**, then your best way of doing it will be using a **HTTP server** to link your Android application with your **Oracle database**. You can use JavaEE, PHP, ASP.NET or any other modern web framework supporting Oracle connections.